# How to Collapsed all menu item

Tags: javascript

I want Collapsed all menu item.

I have menu (that will be added later using jQuery)

```
 <ul class="cd-accordion-menu animated">
    <li class="has-children">
        <input type="checkbox" name ="group-1" id="group-1" checked>
        <label for="group-1">Group 1</label>

        <ul id="ulm">
            <li class="has-children">
                <input type="checkbox" name ="sub-group-1" id="sub-group-1" checked>
                <label for="sub-group-1">Sub Group 1</label>

                <ul id="ulm">
                    <li><a href="#0">Image</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#0">Image</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>               
            <li><a href="#0">Image</a></li>
            <li><a href="#0">Image</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and

I using jQuery

```
<a id="go" href="#">Collapsed</a>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#go').click(function () {
            $('#ulm').css('display', 'none');
        });
    });
</script>
```

But menu not Collapsed

It is link articles https://codyhouse.co/gem/css-multi-level-accordion-menu/

Comment: I don't see any AJAX or jQuery. What seems to go wrong? Your code [works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/0ya2219n/).

Comment: Your function will need to be declared before the `onclick` call. I put the `<script>` in the `<head>` of the document. Could that be the trouble?

Answer (score 0):

if u want to collapse the menu , u should hidden(display:none) the children element of the unchecked element.

```
<script>
function MenuCollapsed() {
     document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].removeAttribute("checked");;
     document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[1].style="display:none";
}
</script>
```

use jQuery will be very simple.

your ajax means jQuery?